# How to execute PowerShell script as local admin, but show results on logged-in users desktop?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Here is my scenario:

I have several computers all on the same domain. Users authenticate against the domain to log into their workstations.

All the local Administrator passwords on the workstations are the same.

What I want to do is execute script remotely using Invoke-Command so that I can create balloon-tip notifications on the users desktop. The problem seems to be that I have to execute the remote script as the local Administrator on each workstation, but I want the balloon tip to popup on the desktop of the logged in user.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm running PowerShell 3.0, but most of the target machines would be 2.0.

Comment: Remote sessions are hosted in a service and not on the users desktop that might be logged in at that moment. There even can be multiple users logged in. With what user you start the remote session does not matter. So your scenario is not correct.

Comment: Well ultimately I was hoping to be able to notify all logged in users on that machine. I thought it may be possible since the code would be executing on their machine, but just as the local admin.